# Having Slim Application Error when installing CPAlead deployer app

Tags: php, slim

While installing CPAlead deployer app I am having this error:

> Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated

I am using Namecheap shared hosting of apache and after login I had this error
[Here is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0YaA.png)

PHP Version- 7.4
Slim Version - 2.6.3

Comment: Please add more details, like the Slim version and the PHP version.

Comment: That must be an *extremely* old version of Slim.